# Regular Expression in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, angularjs

I was creating a regular expression in angular to validate password which should have

1. A number
2. A uppercase letter
3. A lowercase letter
4. Only few symbols i.e !@#$%

position of any character or symbol is not restricted.

I have tried this `regex`

```
/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])/
```

But the above regex takes any special character to be valid... I just want !@#$% this to be valid ele invalid

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: /(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])/

I have tried this but it take any symbol... i want to avoid this thing

Comment: Do you mean by using this with `ng-pattern`?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Angular. You're not adding the special symbols you want to include. Try adding `(?=.*[!@#\$%])` to your regex, after your last group and before the closing `/`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that all the things you want to do are possible in single regex. But you can use a simple validation function that uses some regex's:

```
function validate (pass) {
    if (
        /[A-Z]/.test(pass) && // uppercase letter is required
        /[a-z]/.test(pass) && // lowercase letter is required
        /[0-9]/.test(pass) && // number is required
        /[!@#$%]/.test(pass) && // predefined symbol is required
        !/[^A-Za-z0-9!@#$%]/.test(pass) // there is nothing unwanted 
    ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

[Here is jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6k6bdn55/) to show that it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try a [`ng-change`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIFyy.jpg) listener - something like the following HTML:

```
<input ng-model="pw" ng-change="checkPwPolicy(pw)"> 
<div ng-hide="passwordPolicyValid">Your password is too weak!</div>
```

Combined with this Javascript inside the scope of the controller of this form:

```
function checkPwPolicy(password) {
  var valid = true;

  // at least 1 number
  valid = valid && password.match(/[0-9]/).length > 0;
  // at least 1 uppercase
  valid = valid && password.match(/[A-Z]/).length > 0;

  // ...
  $scope.passwordPolicyValid = valid;
}
```

Some things you could do to improve this implementation are that you could make the change listener fire less often, hide the error message when the password has not been touched, as well as adding more detailed errors to the password policy message.

Comment: the function `checkPwPolicy` should be defined in controller on `$scope`